# How to fix an issue about multiple output lines in algorithm

Tags: algorithms, input, algorithmic, pseudocode, output

When I write a pseudo code using `algorithm` and `algorithmic`.

Output statement overflow a line like below.

```
\begin{algorithm}[!h]
\textbf{Input:} The set of public $parameters$\\
\textbf{Output:} Public key $pk = ({Seed}_{a}\parallel\mathbf{b})$, Private Key $sk = (\mathbf{s})$
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \STATE ${Seed}_{a} \xleftarrow{\$} {\{0, 1\}}^{256}$
    \STATE $\mathbf{a} \gets$ \texttt{SHAKE}256$({Seed}_{a}, n/8)$
    \STATE $\mathbf{s} \xleftarrow{\$} {HWT}_{n}({h}_{s})$
    \STATE $\mathbf{e} \xleftarrow{\$} {\psi}_{cb}^{n}$
    \STATE $\mathbf{b} \gets -\mathbf{a} \ast \mathbf{s} + \mathbf{e}$
    \STATE $pk \gets {Seed}_{a} \parallel \mathbf{b}$
    \STATE $sk \gets \mathbf{s}$
    \RETURN $pk, sk$
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{IND-CPA.KeyGen}
\label{Alg:IND-CPA.KeyGen}
\end{algorithm}
```

[image]

How to make this statement as one line?

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages.

Comment: @OP: The text is just too long to fit in one line. Either remove some text, or reduce the font size for the algorithm.

Comment: Reduce the text size in the Output part of the algorithm environment. You can try the below mentioned snippet : `\textbf{Output:} \footnotesize{Public key $pk = ({Seed}_{a}\parallel\mathbf{b})$, Private Key $sk = (\mathbf{s})$}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you did not give us an compilable TeX code (that means start with `\documentclass` and end the code with `\end{document}`) so I have to guess a little bit. I hope I guessed right. Please next time add an compilable MWE, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Instead of your used text before `\begin{algorithmic}` you can use the two commands `\REQUIRE` and `\ENSURE` like:

```
\REQUIRE The set of public $parameters$
\ENSURE  Public key $pk=({Seed}_{a}\parallel\mathbf{b})$, Private Key $sk=(\mathbf{s})$
```

To get your wished printed text "Input" and "Output" use in the preamble the commands

```
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}} % <=================
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}} % <=================
```

Then you get the "Output" information printed in one line.

Please see the following complete and compilable MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}} % <=================
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}} % <=================

\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[!h]
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\REQUIRE The set of public $parameters$
\ENSURE  Public key $pk=({Seed}_{a}\parallel\mathbf{b})$, Private Key $sk=(\mathbf{s})$
    \STATE ${Seed}_{a} \xleftarrow{\$} {\{0, 1\}}^{256}$
    \STATE $\mathbf{a} \gets$ \texttt{SHAKE}256$({Seed}_{a}, n/8)$
    \STATE $\mathbf{s} \xleftarrow{\$} {HWT}_{n}({h}_{s})$
    \STATE $\mathbf{e} \xleftarrow{\$} {\psi}_{cb}^{n}$
    \STATE $\mathbf{b} \gets -\mathbf{a} \ast \mathbf{s} + \mathbf{e}$
    \STATE $pk \gets {Seed}_{a} \parallel \mathbf{b}$
    \STATE $sk \gets \mathbf{s}$
    \RETURN $pk, sk$
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{IND-CPA.KeyGen}
\label{Alg:IND-CPA.KeyGen}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting algorithm]